# bug in defining an array in factory gril

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I using a `t.text :emails, array: true, default: [], null:false` in my rails 4 migration for emails in the a reporter. There I'm validating each entry with the following code

```
  validates_each :emails do |record, attr, value|
    value.each do |email|
      record.errors.add attr, I18n.t('reporter.error.not_valid_email', email: email) if (email =~ EMAIL_VALIDATION_REGEXP) == nil
    end
  end
```

And I'm getting the following error when I'm creating a instance of the AM class

```
  1) Reporter budget, receipt and member interaction testing the remaining_promise_for_whole_budget_title method for overview of all available budgets
     Failure/Error: @reporter = FactoryGirl.create(:reporter)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `each' for "[\"lkajsdf@gmail.com\"]":String
     # ./app/models/reporter.rb:6:in `block in <class:Reporter>'
     # /Users/malik/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@maalify/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:179:in `call'
```

Here is my factory girl definition

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :reporter do

    name "MyReport"
    donations %W(1 2)
    tanzeems "MyString"
    interval "28"
    emails ["lkajsdf@gmail.com"]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :reporter do
    name "MyReport"
    donations %W(1 2)
    tanzeems "MyString"
    interval "28"
    emails { ["lkajsdf@gmail.com"] }
  end
end
```

Here's the solution. Let it be in the block.

Comment: Stll getting ```Failure/Error: ap @reporter.valid?
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `each' for "[\"lkajsdf@gmail.com\"]":String```